# Why is my reputation down to 16 on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I had around **1700+** reputation points on Stack Overflow, but when I logged in today, it was **16**. There hasn't been any notification or any email from Stack Overflow. Further, Stack Overflow is not displaying my name but some userXXXXXX. Why did this happen? I did not do anything wrong.

I am sure this was not because of serial upvoting. And why has the profile name changed?

[image]

Comment: "Serial upvoting reversed".... Betting a beer this is a nefarious case. (Edit: maybe not. We will see)

Comment: Serial upvoting reversed

Comment: Are you sure you didn't receive any notification?

Comment: yes I am sure, and this upvoting was not serial. Earned this in 2 months. Faced serial upvoting also. I know that case :P

Comment: @Bart Serial upvoting reversed is fine, but why profile name changed ?

Comment: check your profile it look like Serial upvoting reversed -http://stackoverflow.com/users/2761035/user2890143?tab=reputation

Comment: @Bala The 16 rep is not (yet) explain by a serial upvote reversal. The rep after the last event doesn't add up. Profile name changes could be the result of several things which I think I should not speculate about.

Comment: @bart Could be the result of a sock puppet merging maybe?

Comment: @Pëkka that was the speculation I didn't want to make. ;)

Comment: serial upvoting is 314 and 160. But what after repo I earned after that. That was on Nov 11 and I had 1700+ repo till yesterday.

Comment: Further if this was mine, thats on Nov 11, why suddenly today??

Comment: got repo back. I don't know whats happening.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I think you can explain.

Comment: No. Are you asking because of the comment I posted a moment ago? I just noticed that you got your rep back.

Comment: I think one of the staff will have to look into this. Even looking at your records myself has me stumped.

Comment: I'm not seeing 16 rep. Can you post a link to your SO account page, where you have 16 rep?

Comment: It's reversed actually, now repo is 1720 again. :) I dont know what happened. May be SO used my account for some test case :P

Comment: I doubt it. Is this a shared computer? Could you have been logged in as someone else?

Comment: Can you go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation and hit **Trigger Recalc** at the bottom?

Comment: @Oded The user did indeed for a while have 16 rep. It seems an event happened but was reversed based on the *"There were no net reputation changes on this day"* in the reputation for today? Maybe that triggered something?

Comment: @Bart - Nick will be looking at this after the weekend - something strange is going on here (in his words - "it's like a merge without the merge").

Comment: Ah, the I-can't-believe-it's-not-merge merge @Oded. ;) Let's see.

Comment: Can anybody explain, what is a merge without the merge?

Comment: Basically something happened to your account that looks like the result of a merge, but we didn't actually merge any accounts. You're not in trouble (at least not after that serial upvoting thing from last month in your screenshot), it's just something weird happened.

Comment: @Oded The something strange [happened again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213503/reputation-down-from-1900-to-16)