# reputation down from 1900+ to 16

Tags: discussion, reputation

My stackoverflow reputation is again down to 16 from 1900+.  [My previous question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211545/why-is-my-reputation-down-to-16-on-stack-overflow)

And profile name also changed to userXXXXX.

**Note** : There is no notification or email.

[image]

As image shows, reputation is decreased but no reason why.

Can someone explain what and why is this happening to my account?

Comment: Don't understand if Santa has something for me in the stores.

Comment: So it happened again??

Comment: yes. Now my repo is 16 again.

Comment: even if its duplicate, no question has answer.

Comment: @Batty It's still the same bug. So we close them all as dupes of a single one so that the devs can respond appropriately when it's dealt with.

Comment: @Batty Meta sites have special "rules" for duplicates that allow users to close questions as duplicates of un-answered questions.  This is necessary because many duplicate questions do not have answers since they are feature requests or bug reports.  We don't need 12 posts saying the same thing.  This is a sign post to tell you which question to watch for an answer.